# Correct way to apply Minibatch Standard Deviation to Keras GAN layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to improve the stability of my GAN model by adding a standard deviation variable to my layer's feature map. I'm following the example set in the [GANs-in-Action](https://github.com/GANs-in-Action/gans-in-action/blob/master/chapter-6/Chapter_6_PGGAN.ipynb) git. The math itself makes sense to me. The mechanics of my model and the reasons why this addresses mode collapse makes sense to me. However, a shortcoming from the example is that they never actually show how this code is executed.

```
def minibatch_std_layer(layer, group_size=4):
    group_size = keras.backend.minimum(group_size, tf.shape(layer)[0])

    shape = list(keras.backend.int_shape(input))
    shape[0] = tf.shape(input)[0]

    minibatch = keras.backend.reshape(layer,(group_size, -1, shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]))
    minibatch -= tf.reduce_mean(minibatch, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    minibatch = tf.reduce_mean(keras.backend.square(minibatch), axis = 0)
    minibatch = keras.backend.square(minibatch + 1e8)
    minibatch = tf.reduce_mean(minibatch, axis=[1,2,4], keepdims=True)
    minibatch = keras.backend.tile(minibatch,[group_size, 1, shape[2], shape[3]])
    return keras.backend.concatenate([layer, minibatch], axis=1)

def build_discriminator():

    const = ClipConstraint(0.01)

    discriminator_input = Input(shape=(4000,3), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name='discriminator_input')
    
    x = discriminator_input

    x = Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same", kernel_constraint=const)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    x = Conv1D(128, 3, strides=2, padding="same", kernel_constraint=const)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    x = Conv1D(256, 3, strides=3, padding="same", kernel_constraint=const)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    # Trying to add it to the feature map here 
    x = minibatch_std_layer(Conv1D(256, 3, strides=3, padding="same", kernel_constraint=const)(x))

    x = Flatten()(x)

    x = Dense(1000)(x)

    discriminator_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    return Model(discriminator_input, discriminator_output, name='discriminator_model')

d = build_discriminator()
```

No matter how I structure it, I can't get the discriminator to build. It continues to return different types of `AttributeError`s but I've been unable to understand what it wants. Searching the issue, there were lots of Medium posts showing a high level overview of what this does in a progressive GAN, but nothing I could find showing its application.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how the above code is added to a layer?

Comment: what does the 'input' variable in minibatch_std_layer refer to?

Comment: ah? I noticed that too as I was analyzing the code. It's colour coded in my IDE and seems to be the feature map automatically picked up from the `layer`. It didn't seem like that was the spot that was stopping my code from running but maybe I'll check again.

Comment: input in python is a predefined function (this is the reason because it's of another color) but it doesn't matter you can assign a new value to input (not a best practice but u can do). I think that in your case the input variable can be the layer... in this case, I have a proposal if u are interested

Comment: Absolutely. If you can post a way to get that wrapper to work around a layer I think its good information for Stack Overflow users. I have no idea how the author intended for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my proposal...

the problem is related to the `minibatch_std_layer` function. first of all your network deals with 3d data while the original `minibatch_std_layer` deals with 4d data so you need to adapt it. secondly, the `input` variable defined in this function is unknown (also in the source code you cited) so I think the most obvious and logical solution is to consider it as the `layer` variable (the input of `minibatch_std_layer`). with this in mind the modified `minibatch_std_layer` becomes:

```
def minibatch_std_layer(layer, group_size=4):

    group_size = K.minimum(4, layer.shape[0])
    shape = layer.shape

    minibatch = K.reshape(layer,(group_size, -1, shape[1], shape[2]))
    minibatch -= tf.reduce_mean(minibatch, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    minibatch = tf.reduce_mean(K.square(minibatch), axis = 0)
    minibatch = K.square(minibatch + 1e-8) #epsilon=1e-8
    minibatch = tf.reduce_mean(minibatch, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
    minibatch = K.tile(minibatch,[group_size, 1, shape[2]])
    return K.concatenate([layer, minibatch], axis=1)
```

that we can put inside our model in this way:

```
def build_discriminator():

    # const = ClipConstraint(0.01)

    discriminator_input = Input(shape=(4000,3), batch_size=32, name='discriminator_input')
    
    x = discriminator_input

    x = Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    x = Conv1D(128, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    x = Conv1D(256, 3, strides=3, padding="same")(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.3)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    # Trying to add it to the feature map here
    x = Conv1D(256, 3, strides=3, padding="same")(x)
    x = Lambda(minibatch_std_layer)(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)

    x = Dense(1000)(x)

    discriminator_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    return Model(discriminator_input, discriminator_output, name='discriminator_model')
```

I don't know what it's `ClipConstraint` but It doesn't seem problematic. I ran the code with TF 2.2 but also think that it's quite easy to make it run with TF 1 (if u are using it). here the running code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A6UNYkveuHPF7r4-XAe8MuCHZJ-1vcpl?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

For those want using **Minibatch Standard Deviation** as Keras layer here is code:

```
# mini-batch standard deviation layer
class MinibatchStdev(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MinibatchStdev, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # calculate the mean standard deviation across each pixel coord
    def call(self, inputs):
        mean = K.mean(inputs, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        mean_sq_diff = K.mean(K.square(inputs - mean), axis=0, keepdims=True) + 1e-8
        mean_pix = K.mean(K.sqrt(mean_sq_diff), keepdims=True)
        shape = K.shape(inputs)
        output = K.tile(mean_pix, [shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], 1])
        return K.concatenate([inputs, output], axis=-1)

    # define the output shape of the layer
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        input_shape = list(input_shape)
        input_shape[-1] += 1
        return tuple(input_shape)
```

From: [How to Train a Progressive Growing GAN in Keras for Synthesizing Faces](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-a-progressive-growing-gan-in-keras-for-synthesizing-faces/)